# Radial PolarTicks skewed when aspect ratio is not 1

Tags: plotting, ticks

In the following plots, the radial axis `phi == 30 Degree` has a single tick at `r == 1/2`. This tick is skewed (i.e. does not cross the radial axis orthogonally) unless the `PlotRange` is such that the aspect ratio of the plot is 1.

```
Table[
  PolarPlot[1, {phi, 0, Pi/2}
    , PolarAxes -> {False, True}
    , PolarAxesOrigin -> {30 Degree, 1}
    , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, yMax}}
    , PolarTicks -> {{{1/2, "", 0.15}}}
    , TicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]
  ] // {HoldForm["yMax"] == yMax, #} &
  , {yMax, {0.3, 0.5, 1, 2, 5}}
] // Transpose // TableForm
```

[image: Table of polar plots with skewed ticks]

Is there a workaround (other than drawing the ticks manually with primitives)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** A post-processing function that works more generally:

```
ClearAll[fixPolarTicks]
fixPolarTicks[offset_: 15][g_] := 
  Module[{aspectr = (AspectRatio /. Options[g, AspectRatio]), 
    pr = (PlotRange /. Options[g, PlotRange]) /. {{All, All}, {All, All}} -> 
       RegionBounds[Quiet@DiscretizeGraphics[g]], xylengths, oo},
   xylengths = -Subtract @@@ pr; 
   aspectr = aspectr /. Automatic -> Ratios[xylengths][[1]]; 
   oo = offset Normalize[# {1, 1/ aspectr}  xylengths]/Norm[xylengths] &; 
   ReplaceAll[g, {tl : (_Line | _Text) :> 
       (tl /. {Offset[o_, Scaled[a_, b_]] :> Offset[o + oo[a], b], 
         Scaled[a_, b_] :> Offset[oo[a], b]})}]];
```

***Examples:***

```
arlist = {Automatic, .3, 1., 3};

grid = Labeled[Grid[Prepend[Prepend[""]@Table[ar, {ar, arlist}]]@
    Table[Prepend[ymax]@
     Table[PolarPlot[1, {phi, 0, Pi/2}, PolarAxes -> {False, True}, 
        PlotRange -> If[ymax === Automatic, Automatic, {{0, 1}, {0, ymax}}], 
        AspectRatio -> ar, PolarAxesOrigin -> {30 Degree, 1}, 
        PolarTicks -> {Thread[{Subdivide[4], 1. Subdivide[4], .15}]}, 
        TicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]],
     {ar, arlist}], {ymax, arlist}] , Dividers -> All], 
    Style[#, 20] & /@ {"aspect ratio", Rotate[ "ymax", 90 Degree]}, 
    {Top, Left}]
```

[image]

```
grid /. g_Graphics :> fixPolarTicks[][g]
```

[image]

```
Row[{pp = PolarPlot[1/Sqrt[t], {t, .1, 30}, PolarAxes -> {False, True}, 
    PolarAxesOrigin -> {125 Degree, 2}, 
    PolarTicks -> {Thread[{Subdivide[0, 2, 4], 1. Subdivide[0, 2, 4], .1}]}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium], 
  fixPolarTicks[45] @ pp}]
```

[image]

```
Row[{pp2 = Show[pp, AspectRatio -> 3, PlotRange -> {{-2, 1}, {-1, 2}}], 
  fixPolarTicks[45] @ pp2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[fixTicks]
fixTicks = ReplaceAll[Line[s : {__Scaled}] :> 
   Line[MapAt[Function[x, x/Normalize[-Subtract @@@ PlotRange[#], Min]],  s, 
     {All, 1}]]] @ # &;

Table[fixTicks@
     PolarPlot[1, {phi, 0, Pi/2}, PolarAxes -> {False, True}, 
      PolarAxesOrigin -> {30 Degree, 1}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, yMax}}, 
      PolarTicks -> {{{1/2, "", 0.15}}}, 
      TicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]] // {HoldForm["yMax"] == 
       yMax, #} &, {yMax, {0.3, 0.5, 1, 2, 5}}] // 
  Transpose // TableForm
```

[image]